# Can't access form element in IE because it 'is undefined'. Works ok in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cross-browser

It's strange because I only get 1 error in IE: 'sTime is undefined'.  sTime is the ID of one of the many input elements in my form.  Everything works fine in Chrome and FF.  Here's a link to the code:

http://la.truxmap.com/sched.html

and the form html:

```
<form id="addNewTruck" class='updateschedule' action="javascript:sub(sTime.value, eTime.value, lat.value, lng.value, street.value);"> 

    <b style="color:green;">Opening at: </b> 
        <input id="sTime" name="sTime" title="Opening time" value="Click to set opening time" class="datetimepicker"/> 

    <b style="color:red;">Closing at: </b> 
        <input id="eTime" name= "eTime" title="Closing time" value="Click to set closing time" class="datetimepicker"/> 

    <b style="color:blue;">Address: </b> 
        <input type='text' name='street' id='street' class='text street' autocomplete='off'/> 
        <input id='submit' class='submit' style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" type="submit" value='Add new stop'/> 
    <div id='suggests' class='auto_complete' style='display:none'></div> 
        <input type='hidden' name='lat' id='lat'/> 
        <input type='hidden' name='lng' id='lng'/> 
        <input type='hidden' value='CA' name='state' id='state' class='text state' />
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try putting the JavaScript into the `onsubmit` event rather than `action`
- Address the form elements less ambiguously in the JS, e.g. using `this.elements.sTime`. It could be that the element name is used elsewhere in the document.

Comment: Using onsubmit rather than action seems to allow IE to access the input elements. now ie dislikes the regex i use to format the dateString... any idea what may be causing that?

Comment: @culov nope, sorry. Maybe worth a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript in form's action should work well. 
Maybe you should use instead of `sTime.value` the following:

```
document.forms[0].sTime.value
```

Of course this means that this form is the first in your page (else you must change `...forms[0]...` into `...forms['formname']...` or `...forms[<form index>]...`)